# Kibana is redirecting me to 302. Not able to curl from the machine

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7, elasticsearch-7

ELK 7.8 is running on AWS EC2.

Kibana is redirecting me to 302.
**Curl output for kibana pasted here:**

ubuntu@ip-**-128-43-**:/etc/kibana$ curl -IL **.128.43.**:5601
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
location: /spaces/enter
kbn-name: ip-**-128-43-**
kbn-license-sig: 93f22251010dedca4781a015792c765fd0560b0c7a64ff26c4e33cd80837c712
kbn-xpack-sig: ef42adb69cd0ad9c36eb0323e8819b1d
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-length: 0
Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2020 05:36:23 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
kbn-name: ip-**-128-43-**
kbn-license-sig: 93f22251010dedca4781a015792c765fd0560b0c7a64ff26c4e33cd80837c712
kbn-xpack-sig: ef42adb69cd0ad9c36eb0323e8819b1d
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-length: 92
Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2020 05:36:23 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

**Kibana service is running**

**Kibana logs**

````
{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2020-07-28T05:39:28Z","tags":[],"pid":14119,"method":"get","statusCode":302,"req":{"url":"/","method":"get","headers":{"host":"**.128.43.**:5601","connection":"close","user-agent":"ELB-HealthChecker/2.0","accept-encoding":"gzip, compressed"},"remoteAddress":"**.128.43.69","userAgent":"**.128.43.69"},"res":{"statusCode":302,"responseTime":20,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET / 302 20ms - 9.0B"}```

**$ netstat -tupl | grep 5601**
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 ip-**-128-43-**.e:5601 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

**Here is my kibana.yml config**

server.host: **.128.43.**
xpack.security.enabled: false
server.port: 5601
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true

** Kibana version: 7.8.0 **


Any help suggestion would be highly appreciated.
````